# Error in models running Django 1.9.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Whenever I try to run, I'm getting the following error described below. Already I researched a solution, but I can not make it work.

> Exception Type:    ValueError
>       Exception Value:
>       ModelForm has no model class specified.
>       Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in **init**, line 275
>       Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>       Python Version: 2.7.6

Erro Traceback

> File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/envelope/views.py" in cad_professor
>     67.         form = ProfessorForm()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in **init**
>     275.             raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')  
def cad_professor(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfessorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context['success'] = True
    else:
        form = ProfessorForm()
context['form'] = form
template_name = 'envelope/cad_professor.html'
return render(request,template_name , context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Professor

class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class meta:
        model = Professor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `meta` spelling is wrong. Change to:

```
class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Professor
```

Comment: That lack of attention